# Configure kapacitor CLI to communicate to Remote Kapacitor

Tags: influxdb, kapacitor

How to configure kapacitor CLI to communicate with remote kapacitor.

Comment: Which edition are you wanting to do this on? Asking because only Kapacitor enterprise supports clustering.

Answer (score 1):

Set a KAPACITOR_URL env variable pointing to your host:port.

After this is set, just run kapacitor + commands to retrieve data from tasks, etc

Answer (score 0):

It can be done even without env changes, e.g.

```
kapacitor -url http://someotherhost:9092 <do some>
```